# Durandal SPA on iPad goes to browser when navigating

Tags: asp.net, ipad, durandal

Created ASP.Net SPA using Durandal. Added a forms login page that is hit prior to the SPA.  When accessed on an iPad and saved to Home screen it opens like a native app, I can login and still stays in same window when it opens the SPA.  BUT as soon as I navigate to another route it opens Safari instead.

Is there something I'm missing or any possible way I can avoid this, it would be nice if I can keep it looking like a native app.

EDIT:
As required logic from shell.js from Durandal viewmodels folder:

```
define(['plugins/router', 'durandal/app'], function (router, app) {
return {
    router: router,
    activate: function () {
        router.map([
            { route: '', title:'Actions', moduleId: 'viewmodels/actions', nav: true },
            { route: 'welcome', title:'Welcome', moduleId: 'viewmodels/welcome', nav: true },
            { route: 'flickr', moduleId: 'viewmodels/flickr', nav: true },
            { route: 'clients', moduleId: 'viewmodels/clients', nav: true },
            { route: 'client/:id', moduleId: 'viewmodels/client', nav: false }
        ]).buildNavigationModel();

        return router.activate();
    },
    attached: function () {
        $("#logoff").show();
    }
};
});
```

You can simply create a new Application in VS 2012+ using the downloadable Durandal SPA template from asp.net site.

Logic from shell.html:

```
<ul class="nav" data-bind="foreach: router.navigationModel">
            <li data-bind="css: { active: isActive }">
                <a data-bind="attr: { href: hash }, html: title"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Can you show the logic you are using to load the next page?

Comment: Added via edit.  Typically a route will be #clients, #/client/9 etc

Comment: Sure, that makes sense, but can you show an example of a button or a call to load the next page from whereever you are doing it?  ie <button data-bind="click: setRoute">

Comment: It's just from an a tag, added code for shell.html

Comment: Can you change your a tag to this - <a data-bind="attr: { href: hash }, text: hash"></a> and make sure it is showing #route for each route, and that is mapping back to a route?

Comment: Changed, routes work ok and displaying as #welcome, #clients as you would expect.

Comment: Oooooh I see what you are saying now, my apologies.  Basically you are saying that you are saving the site to your local iPad and it opens Safari on redirect's.

Comment: Not quite, I deploy the site on my computer locally or online and navigate to the address of the web application from the iPad.  I use the icon at the top to select to put on main screen as a shortcut.  When tapping this it opens site like a native app but when clicking on a route it then opens safari at the new route instead of changing it where it is.